# Is there a way to allow only one button out of a set to be selected?

Tags: javascript, html, cordova

I guess I'm looking to try and make radio buttons except with actual buttons in HTML/Cordova.

My app will have several questions with buttons underneath them for answers. When the user presses a button for a question, I want it to highlight that button to indicate that that's what is locked in, and unhighlight any previous answers to that question (while not affecting any of the buttons for other questions).

Is there an efficient way to do this? Would horizontally aligned radio buttons with images be the best way? Or is there some sort of standard way to do this with simple HTML buttons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using the `label` tag.

For example:

HTML:

```
<form>
  <input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio1" value="radio1" />
  <label for="radio1"></label>
  <input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio2" value="radio2" />
  <label for="radio2"></label>
</form>
```

CSS:

```
label { 
    display: inline-block;
    width:30px; height:30px;
    margin: 0 20px;
    background-color: red; }

input { display: none; }

input:checked + label { background-color: green; }
```

Working fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/bK73E/

You can set any background image and properties on the label to make it look the way you want.

Comment: Thank you. That's exactly what I wanted. The only problem is that I wanted to create a template that could be copied by Javascript dynamically, because the questions can change dynamically too. If I copy this as a template the duplicate ids would make it break. Is there a way to do this? Or should I just change the ids of the inputs and fors for the labels every time? Also if I put text in the labels, is it possible align it in the center of the box vertically? Text-align only aligns it horizontally.

Comment: You've asked many a question there! Yes you'd need unique ids for this to work. You can only pair up a label with an input using a unique ID. If you're using javascript anyway, you can probably add some script to create the fors and ids for you.
As for vertical align, there's a few ways to do it. First way is line-height. E.g. if the label has height:60px, set line-height:60px on it too. Otherwise you can use absolute positioning (slightly more complex code required). Check out this for example: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/absolute-center-vertical-horizontal-an-image/

Comment: Thank you so much. Now I can finally get started!

Answer (score 0):

Well that's what the Radio buttons do! If you are using this: `<input type="radio" name="thisquest" value="" /><input type="radio" name="thisquest" value="" />` 
Else if you do something like!

```
<input type="radio" name="male" value="male"/><input type="radio" name="female" value="female" />
```

They won't match and both will be checked!

No the vertical one's would be better! Also, if you wanna show them some images its a better idea!